# Linear combinations of eigenvectors corresponding to absolute extrema of spectrum of a hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-minima, variational-analysis

Consider a finite-dimensional complex (hermitian, for simplicity) matrix whose spectrum has a minimum $M_0$ and maximum $M_1$.

By the variational theorem (this is the way it's called in physics, I'm not sure what is its name in mathematics, but I believe it's related to the [Min-Max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)), any vector whose expectation value (Rayleigh–Ritz quotient) is $M_0$ ($M_1$) is also an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $M_0$ ($M_1$). This should also hold when $M_0$ ($M_1$) is degenerate (its corresponding eigenspace has dimension greater than one).
More explicitly, the expectation value of a vector $v$ on a matrix $A$ is:

$$ \frac{(v,Av)}{(v,v)} $$

where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the dot product and $Av$ is  the action of $A$ on $v$, if viewed as operator on an abstract vector space, or the row-by-column multiplication of the matrix $A$ and column vector $v$.

The variational theorem then states:

$$ \frac{(v,Av)}{(v,v)} = M_0 \iff Av = M_0v$$ $$\frac{(v,Av)}{(v,v)} = M_1 \iff Av = M_1v $$

Is it true then that, given a state whose expectation value is $M_0$ ($M_1$), it can **only** be written as a linear of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $M_0$ ($M_1$).

To be precise, given a finite set of vectors $w_k$ whose linear combination is $v$ (with expectation value $M_0$, thus an eigenvector by the variational theorem), then all $w_k$ are necessarily eigenvectors with eigenvalue $M_0$:
$$ \frac{(v,Av)}{(v,v)} = M_0 \iff v = \sum_k c_k w_k, Aw_k = M_0w_k$$

I would assume this to be true, since any contribution with eigenvalue larger than $M_0$ (smaller than $M_1$) would result in an increase (decrease) of the expectation value above $M_0$ (below $M_1$), but I don't know how to prove it.

Am I missing something? Can anyone give me a counterexample? Have I made an additional assumption I'm forgetting, it being absent in the "physics" statement of the variational theorem?

Comment: Your post is very unclear. You are mentioning expectations, but you do not really explain what they are. Some words are also missing. Please consider adding mathematical details in the form of mathematical expressions and not with unclear words and terminology.

Comment: Yes, that's right. A linear combination of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $M_i$ is just another eigenvector with eigenvalue $M_i$, so this already follows from the variational theorem as you've quoted it. The Hermitian assumption is not just "for simplicity" here; without it the statement is quite false.

Comment: @KBS I wrote the equivalent of expectation value as Rayleigh-Ritz quotient, which is mentioned in the Min-Max theorem I linked. I can write it explicitly so that it's not necessary to go outside this page. Apart from that and explicitly writing what is a 'linear combination', I'm not sure how else to improve my wording.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Isn't it still true for any diagonalizable matrix with real spectrum (such that it's still meaningful to speak about minimum and maximum)? (or are such operators all hermitian?)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Then perhaps I'm missing something here. I'm asking this question because I'm considering the absolute value of the dot product of a given state $v$ with the eigenbasis of a certain operator $U$, $|(w_k,v)|^2$ (the "overlap"). Then, I'm looking at the expectation value of $w_k$ with respect to a hermitian operator $O$. Given that $v$ has expectation value which is equal to the maximum eigenvalue of $O$, I would expect all $w_k$ with non zero "overlap" also to have expectation value with respect to $O$ equal to the maximum, but this is not the case. Are my calculations wrong?

Comment: As for your second question, this is quite a different situation; I was assuming that $U$ and $O$ were the same operator. The answer to this question is no: the $w_k$ can be an arbitrary basis, and in particular don't have to be eigenvectors of $A$ (or $O$) at all.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. Indeed, I was talking about a generic basis/choice of vectors $w_k$. Having expanded the expectation value (as I should have), I can see that there are off-diagonal elements $(w_k,Ow_{k'})$ which can contribute a negative or positive value, such that $(v,Ov)$ can still be $M_0$ or $M_1$. If you wish, you can insert these comments into an answer I could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first let's clear up the precise statement of the [variational theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem); the Hermitian assumption is necessary, not just "for simplicity," and without it the theorem is false. If $A$ is an arbitrary matrix then the Rayleigh quotient $R_A(x) = \frac{\langle Ax, x \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle}$ depends only on the Hermitian part of $A$; we can write $A$ uniquely as sum of a Hermitian and a skew-Hermitian matrix, namely

$$A = \frac{A + A^{\dagger}}{2} + \frac{A - A^{\dagger}}{2}$$

and we have $\langle Ax, x \rangle = \langle \frac{A + A^{\dagger}}{2} x, x \rangle$. So in this case the minimum and maximum of $R_A$ is controlled by the eigenvalues of $\frac{A + A^{\dagger}}{2}$, not of $A$. (I misspoke in the comments about singular values; those control the minimum and maximum of a different function, namely $\frac{\langle Ax, Ax \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle}$.)

Anyway, the answer to your question is no, the $w_k$ can be arbitrary and in particular don't have to be eigenvectors of $A$ at all. This is not in contradiction with the fact that their Rayleigh quotients $R_A(w_k)$ must be between $M_0$ and $M_1$ because, as you say, if you expand out $\langle Av, v \rangle$ in terms of the $w_k$ there are cross terms $\langle Aw_i, w_j \rangle$ contributing to the sum. The cross terms do disappear if the $w_k$ are eigenvectors of $A$, which is the question I thought you were originally asking; in that case the $w_k$ would have to be eigenvectors with eigenvalue $M_0$ resp. $M_1$.